# Get the offset position of a table using its index with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have two tables in a page. And i print their top co-ordinates using jQuery's `$.offset().top`.

```
$("table").offset().top
```

prints the first table offsets. Doesn't `$("table")` select all the tables? How does it print just the first table's co-ordinates?

And when i try to print the second table's offset position using `$("table")[1]`, it says `$("table")[1].offset` is `undefined`

Jsfiddle link is at, 
http://jsfiddle.net/JfGVE/805/

Note: I can get the results using table's id but i am looking for a solution that uses table's index to get its offset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use jQuery methods on DOM elements.

A [jQuery object](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/) contains DOM elements, and you were trying to use the jQuery method `.offset()` on one of the DOM elements in the jQuery object.

Use the [`.eq()` method](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) in order to access a jQuery object by its index instead:

```
$("table").eq(1).offset().top;
```

<sub>(As a side-note, the `.eq()` method's index is zero-based, so `.eq(1)` is the second element.)</sub>

---

It's also worth mentioning that you can wrap the DOM element `$("table")[1]` with `$()` in order to use it as a jQuery object:

```
$($("table")[1]).offset().top
```

Answer (score 2):

jquery docs for offset():

> Get the current coordinates of the first element in the set of matched
>   elements, relative to the document.

says it all

Answer (score 2):

You can either iterate over the tables and store their offset in an array. When you access the table as $("table")[1], it becomes a javascript object. In order to get the offset for this element you can use any of the following:

```
$("table").eq(1).offset().top

or 

$($("table")[1]).offset().top
```

This is because .offset() is a jquery function and not a javascript funtion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.eq()` instead.

```
console.log("the first table offset is " +$("table").eq(1).offset().top)
```